# Video quality issues with MediaElement.JS and Flash

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

Is there any configuration option for [MediaElement.JS](http://mediaelementjs.com/) to control video quality when using the SWF player? When running the Video from VLC it looks just fine, but when I open it in the browser the quality is worse.. something like when no anti aliasing is applied (see image below).

Any thoughts?

[image: Left VLC, Right MediaElement]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question: I found out that the correct term in this case is "smoothing", instead of "anti aliasing". Also, MediaElement.js has an option for that called `enablePluginSmoothing` which is set to `false` by default. It was necessary to read the source code to discover this option, as it is not (yet) documented.

So, just set `enablePluginSmoothing` to `true` when creating the component, and video playback quality should be better.