# MediaElement.js not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, mediaelement.js

So I've read other posts and the supposed fixes for IE8 but none have seemed to work. The main player on the MediaElementjs.com site doesn't even work in IE8.

Can anyone point me to a site that they know uses mediaelement.js successfully in IE8?

The plan being to view source and repeat what they've done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My site seems to work in IE8, here is a page with a video: http://www.theguitarlesson.com/guitar-lessons/white-christmas-guitar-lesson-bing-crosby/

I had to set `enablePluginSmoothing` to true as describe here, since the Flash playback quality was baaaaad out of the box, but didn't do anything else. That I found here: [Video quality issues with MediaElement.JS and Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665184/video-quality-issues-with-mediaelement-js-and-flash)

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to put the

```
<script>$('audio').mediaelementplayer();</script>
```

last in the body element for it to work in IE8 and other old IE versions. I'd put it in the head, since the instructions say the link to the script has to be in the head if you want to support old versions of IE so I assumed the call would have to go there too.

If you've copied the object tags from the full video example (Option B on the site) then IE will load the Flash player but won't add the mediaelement.js markup that's needed to load the media.

The best example to work from for audio is the `demo/mediaelementplayer-audio.html` page in the zipped download in the latest version (you'll need to download the media as well, not sure why that's separate but it's here: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement-files/ ). Copy the pieces of it into your page, in the same places, then replace with your own file paths. If that doesn't work, then the problem is likely with your MIME type or CSS visibility properties.

Comment: +1, moving the call to mediaelementplayer() to the footer fixed it for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Issue calls after $(document).ready, or when media element has loaded.